# Ldif to shadow file conversion

Tags: python

I have been trying to do some password cracking using L0phtcrack. I have a LDIF file that cannot be imported in to l0phtcrack as it is. lophtcrack does not also import from a csv file. The only option that I have using lophtcrack is to import from a Unix shadow file. Has anyone tried out converting a ldif file to a shadow file format in python ? If yes, would you mind sharing the script here.

Thanks

UPDATE - I made a few edits to code that i found online and got it to work. I now have a shadow file from my LDIF extract.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Read in a ldap/ldif file and split out a unix-formated password file to run in
john the ripper for password auditing.

Typical usage (on the ldap server):
    Dump the ldap database
        slapcat > ldif.out
    Convert it to passwd format
        ldap-passwd-dump.py ldif.out passwd.out
    Run john to crack passwords
        john passwd.out

Aaron Peterson <aaron@midnightresearch.com>
"""

import sys, base64, re, os

class Results:
    """
    Keep all user results here
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.users = []

    def addUser(self, user):
        # Check for duplicates
        dupe = 0
        for u in self.users:
            if u.uid == user.uid:
                dupe = 1
                break
        if not dupe:
            print " [*] Adding new user [%s, %s] to results" % (user.cn, user.uid)
            self.users.append(user)
        else:
            print " [*] Not adding duplicate user [%s]" % user.cn

class User(list):
    def __init__(self, hash=None, base64=None, password=None, cn=None, uid=None):
        self.hash = hash
        self.uid = uid
        self.base64 = base64
        self.password = password
        self.cn = cn
        list.__init__(self)

class  LDIFCrack:
    def main(self):
        # Open file
        f = open(self.ldif, "r")
        # Load in the first user
        user = User()
        isInGroup=0
        # Load lines into a "user"
        for line in f:
            if re.compile(r"^\s*$").search(line):
                # Only append the old user if it's in the right group, and has a password set
                if isInGroup and user.hash:
                    self.results.addUser(user)
                # Reset user and counter
                user = User()
                isInGroup=0
            # Make sure we test the right groups
            if re.compile(self.groupMatch).search(line):
                isInGroup=1

            # Pull out the password
            match = re.compile(r"userpassword: (.*)$").search(line)
            if match:
                user.hash = match.group(1)

            # uid
            match = re.compile(r"uid: (.*)$").search(line)
            if match:
                user.uid= match.group(1)
            # Grab the common name
            matchCn = re.compile(r"cn: (.*)$").search(line)
            if matchCn:
                user.cn = matchCn.group(1)

    def printPasswd(self, file):
        f = open(file, "w")
        for user in self.results.users:
            line = "%s:%s:::%s" % (user.uid, user.hash, user.cn)
            f.write(line + "\n")
            print " [*] %s" % line
        f.close()
        print " [*] Wrote [%s] password lines to [%s] " % (len(self.results.users), file)

    def __init__(self, ldif, groupMatch):
        self.ldif = ldif
        self.results = Results()
        self.groupMatch = groupMatch
        self.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print "\nusage: %s <ldif file> <output password file> [<user matchString>]" % sys.argv[0]
        print "       example: %s ldif.out passwd.txt \"^ou: MyGroup\"" % sys.argv[0]
        print "       (matchString default is \"objectClass: posixAccount\")\n"
        sys.exit(1)

    ldif = sys.argv[1]
    passwdFile = sys.argv[2]
    if not os.path.exists(ldif):
        print " [!] LDIF Input file [%s] does not exist..." % ldif
        sys.exit(1)
    if os.path.exists(passwdFile):
        print " [!] Won't overwrite existing passwd file [%s]" % passwdFile
        sys.exit(1)

    # Will match the user against this group before cracking it if it's set
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        groupMatch = sys.argv[3]
    else:
        groupMatch = "objectClass: posixAccount"
    ldifcrack = LDIFCrack(ldif, groupMatch)
    ldifcrack.printPasswd(passwdFile)

    print " [*] Done"
```

Comment: obligatory first question: what did you try to do? otherwise it doesn't qualify as practical programming question https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks.. Edited the original question to add the code